# Index on a Varchar?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

We're suffering some heavy table locking issues in production. I have noticed that I created a stored procedure which gets a list of orders by order number. Order number is a VARCHAR(150). There is no index of any type on this column.

At the moment, there is a LOT of NULL values in this column. However, over time (This table went live recently), the table will grow significantly. No more NULL values will be added in this time.

My question is two fold. Firstly, would an index be beneficial here. The proc is heavily used. And if so, should it be clustered or not? Data is things like CP123456, DR126512.

The second question, which probably influences the first question is - would it be beneficial to change the column to a CHAR(10), as it 'seems' the order number is always the same size. Is there any speed benefit in putting an index on a fixed length CHAR, as opposed to a VARCHAR(150)?

(The different in size is because of unknown requirements when the column was created).

SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, absolutely! Go right ahead and add an index. Clustering the index is probably unnecessary here, and will not be possible anyway if you already have another clustered index (such as the primary key) on the table.
2. Changing the column to a `CHAR(10)` might have some benefits in terms of storage size, but it's unlikely to make a particularly great difference in index performance. I'd skip it for now.

Comment: You can certainly have non-clustered primary keys in ms sql server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have references to cite on this, only experience / anecdotal evidence.

Firstly, queries can nearly always be improved through use of indexes.  The exact benefit depends on the query.
- If a query requires only specific records / a small portion of the table, an index will help
- If a query requires the whole table, but could benefit from ordered data, an index will help

Clustered indexes generally provide performance benefits over non-clustered indexes.  In a very simplified sense, using a non-clustered index is like using two tables and joining them (The search friendly index is used first, which is then joined to the data itself - Unless the index contains all the data fields you need).

A consideration here, however, is the order in which data is added to your table.  If your clustered index means that data is often inserted or deleted at the middle of the table, you'll get fragmentation and other artefacts.  In my experience, however, awareness and consideration to this is only needed in extreme situations.

In short, DEFINITELY index your data.  And the clustered index is normally best placed to serve your worst performing queries.

As for the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR?  In the olden days it was important to keep variable length fields at the end of your data, to make the fixed length fields easier to identify.  This meant that having a VARCHAR field as your first field, and using it as a unique identifier, was pretty poor.

Nowadays, the performance difference is marginal.  Personally, I'd still keep unique identifiers as fixed length though.  Variable length data won't normally have noticeable performance costs, but when you're actually making comparisons for join predicates, etc., it's much tidier to have fixed length fields if possible.